# Как можно воспользоваться кодом Autofac на c#?

Tags: c#, autofac

Вот есть такая строка кода [учебник Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => new A { B = c.Resolve<B>() });
var container = builder.Build();
```

Скажите пожалста, для какого это случая ? Например, если для таких классов - то будет ошибка выполнения. А как нужно изменить класс А чтобы не было ошибки ?

```
 public class B { }

 public class A
 {
   public B B { get; set; }

   public A() { }
 }
```

ошибка: `The requested service 'ConsoleApp1.B' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.`

Comment: Какая ошибка? Включу режим ванги и предположу, что что-то по типу `B has not been registered`. У вас класс A требует класс B, который ищется также в контейнере, теперь вопрос - он там есть? Вы зарегистрировали тип `B` в контейнере? На будущее, пожалуйста, если "ОШИБКА", значит не просто пишете "у меня ошибка", а прикладываете все необходимое, что выдается вам. P.S. Как и сказано в документации, такая конструкция не обязательна, достаточно пометить свойство `B` как `required`, контейнер это поймет и сам внедрит тип.

Comment: вот весь код для контейнера       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.Register(c => new A { B = c.Resolve<B>() });
      var container = builder.Build();  . . . . А вот ошибка: "The requested service 'ConsoleApp1.B' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: Переведите ошибку, что там сказано? И еще раз прочитайте мой первый комментарий.

Comment: Перевел . . . Поэтому если я вместо метода Resolve() пишу метод ResolveOptional() то ошибка пропадает. Однако это уже не будет то код что вот тут: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection.  А мне хотелось бы узнать для какого именно случая там написан оригинальный код

Comment: Еще раз перечитайте мой первый комментарий, прям процитирую "У вас класс A требует класс B, который ищется также в контейнере, теперь вопрос - он там есть? Вы зарегистрировали тип B в контейнере?" Контейнеры - это не магия, это простой набор типов добавленных в некий список, из которого потом создается нужный объект по требованию. Ваш код требует тип В, но вы не добавили его в контейнер. Вот уберите строку с регистрацией типа А, получите туже ошибку, что типа нет в контейнере, но уже ругаться будет на тип А. Если вы все еще не поняли... Зарегистрируйте В в контейнере!

Comment: Спасибо, сделал как вы сказали . . . получилось . . . к тому же вы помогли мне не будущее немного искать причину в ошибках  . . . еще раз большое спасибо